# Archivo de texto no se guarda como deseo

Tags: archivo, algoritmos, java-8

El problema que tengo es que al guardar el archivo de texto no se guarda como deseo. Lo que quiero es que se guarde de esta manera:

> ```
> a,b,c,
> d,e,f,
> ```

Pero se guarda de esta manera:

> ```
> a,b,c,d,e,f,
> ```

Estoy utilizando una clase Nodo y name representa el nombre del archivo.
Les dejo el codigo de mi problema:

```
public void recorrer(Nodo n,String name){
    String aux = "";
    try{
        
        if(n!=null){
            

            if(n.getIzquierda()==null && n.getDerecha()==null){
                aux = ""+","+n.getAlu().getCodigo()+","+" "+",";
            }
            if(n.getIzquierda()==null && n.getDerecha()!=null){
                aux = "\n"+","+n.getAlu().getCodigo()+","+n.getDerecha().getAlu().getIndice()+",";
            }
            if(n.getIzquierda()!=null && n.getDerecha()==null){
                aux =""+ n.getIzquierda().getAlu().getIndice()+","+n.getAlu().getCodigo()+","+" "+",";
            }
            if(n.getIzquierda()!=null && n.getDerecha()!=null){
               aux= n.getIzquierda().getAlu().getIndice()+","+n.getAlu().getCodigo()+","+n.getDerecha().getAlu().getIndice()+",";
            }

           File archivo = new File(name);
           FileWriter f = new FileWriter(archivo,true);
            
            f.write(aux+"\n");
            f.close();
            recorrer(n.getIzquierda(),name);
            recorrer(n.getDerecha(),name);            
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }   
}
```

Este código lo hice utilizando Java 1.8 y el editor JCreator 4.5.
Me pueden explicar la razón, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Para que podamos ayudarte antes tienes que indicar claramente cuales son las condiciones para introducir ese salto de línea que estás echando en falta.
Puedes editar tu entrada para incluir la descripción del ejercicio.
Viendo tu código no acabo de entenderlo bien.

También sería interesante que incluyeras el código donde se crea esa estructura arbórea para que quien quiera ayudarte pueda reproducirlo más fácilmente.

Por último, si quieres que la gente entienda tu problema solo viendo el código tienes que hacerlo lo más legible posible. En tu código hay operaciones que no tienen ningún efecto, son supérfluas, o que son fácilmente simplificables. **Mientras menos código haya más fácil será de entender.**

Y pon espacios de separación entre operaciones para facilitar la lectura. ¿En un libro todas las palabras están pegadas entre si?

Por ejemplo

```
aux = ""+","+n.getAlu().getCodigo()+","+" "+",";
```

Es igual a

```
aux = "," + n.getAlu().getCodigo() + ", ,";
```

Aquí tienes una versión simplificada de tu código. El [operador ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario) ayuda a reducir el número de bloques if que habías definido.

```
public void recorrer(Nodo n, String name) {
        
        try {
            
            if (n != null) {                

                String izquierda = 
                 (n.getIzquierda() != null) ? n.getIzquierda().getAlu().getIndice() : "";
                        
                String derecha =
                 (n.getDerecha() != null) ? n.getDerecha().getAlu().getIndice() : "";

                String nodoActual = 
                  izquierda + "," + n.getAlu().getCodigo() + "," + derecha;
                
                File archivo = new File(name);
                FileWriter f = new FileWriter(archivo,true);
                
                f.write(nodoActual + "\n");
                f.close();
                
                recorrer(n.getIzquierda(), name);
                recorrer(n.getDerecha(), name);            
            }
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }   
    }
```

Si sabes claramente cuando hay que introducir un salto de línea a la izquierda, `condicion`, habría que añadirlo de forma similar a esta

```
String saltoLinea = (condicion) ? "\n" : "";

String nodoActual = 
     saltoLinea + izquierda + "," + n.getAlu().getCodigo() + "," + derecha;
```